# How can I solve this failed to remotely push refs to section.io Pulling required proxy images

Tags: git, terminal, developer-tools

I was pushing my developer-pop configurations to remote when this error popped up. I don't know what to do.
My commands and results above were:

```sh
git remote add developer-pop http://192.168.99.101:30090/app/
```

and

```sh
git push developer-pop
```

The results:

```sh
john@john:~/bootcamp.section.io$ git push developer-pop
Enumerating objects: 203, done.
Counting objects: 100% (203/203), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (145/145), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 310.18 KiB | 77.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 51), reused 203 (delta 51), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: 
remote: varnish image not found, pulling from repository
remote: modsecurity image not found, pulling from repository
remote: Pulling required proxy images, please try again shortly
To http://192.168.99.101:30090/app/
 ! [remote rejected] Production -> Production (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.99.101:30090/app/'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

If you get this message “Pulling required proxy images, please try again shortly”, that means that your machine does not have the proxy images locally and has begun downloading them.
Just *relax* and give the system some time off (about 5 min or so) as it says in the error. Then try again.

The **outcome**:

````sh
john@john:~/bootcamp.section.io$ git push developer-pop
Enumerating objects: 203, done.
Counting objects: 100% (203/203), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (145/145), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 310.18 KiB | 77.55 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 51), reused 203 (delta 51), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (51/51), done.
remote: Validating configuration for proxy varnish...
remote: Validating configuration for proxy modsecurity...
To http://192.168.99.101:30090/app/
 * [new branch]      Production -> Production```
````